# Bootstrap 4 carousel which is fixed to top is hiding the next section

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap 4 navbar and carousel. The carousel is fixed to the top of the page and the navbar is above it. Now I am working on the next section(about us) but it is going under the carousel. I tried fixing it with overflow hidden but it isn't working. I can see small portion of about us section coming out but thats all. Here's my fiddle with html and css only.

https://jsfiddle.net/zakero/8o3acdx0/1/

```
<header class="headersection">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPIRIT8</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<section class="slider">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>WELCOME ON <span>SPIRIT8</span></h5>
              <p>We are a digital agency with <span>years of experience</span> and with <span>extraordinary people</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>WELCOME ON <span>SPIRIT8</span></h5>
              <p>We are a digital agency with <span>years of experience</span> and with <span>extraordinary people</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/banner.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>WELCOME ON <span>SPIRIT8</span></h5>
              <p>We are a digital agency with <span>years of experience</span> and with <span>extraordinary people</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="aboutus">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="aboutusimg">
                    <img src="img/1.png">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="aboutusdesc">
                    <h4>ABOUT US</h4>
                    <h2>SOME WORDS <span>ABOUT US</span></h2>
                    <hr>
                    <p>We love building and rebuilding brands through our specific skills. Using color, fonts and illustration, we brand companies in a way they will never forget.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Mission - <span>We deliver uniqueness and quality</span></li>
                        <li>Skills - <span>Delivering fast and excellent results</span></li>
                        <li>Clients - <span>Satisfied clients thanks to our experience.</span></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Someone please help a brother in need.

PS. I have looked for previous posts with the same problem. But I only found one without any solution so I am posting again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `position: absolute;` from `slider` class

For navbar issue update the class as,

```
.headersection {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank you. But the slider doesn't go underneath the header(navbar) if I remove that class. I have used position relative in header section.Any solution for that?

Comment: Omg wow. It worked. Thank you so much. You have been helpful Sir.